# Calculating the days in a certain period

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a form which is connected to database,
so this form can have more blocks, where each block have date from, date until
for example

| Block | Date_From | Date_until |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25.07.2022 | 11.08.2022 |
| 2 | 05.08.2022 | 15.08.2022 |
| 3 | 10.08.2022 | 20.08.2022 |
| 4 | 11.08.2022 | 05.09.2022 |

I'm trying to make a `SELECT` statement which going to display number of days between `01.08.2022` and `31.08.2022`.

- first block date_from  = 25.07.2022, date_until = 11.08.2022 ->11 days
- second block and third block should remain NULL or some default text, because the interval of these blocks is in fourth block.
- fourth block date_from = 11.08.2022, date_until = 05.09.2022-> 20 days (until the end of the month).

Could you help me guys with creating this select? The select should have `date_from`, `date_until` and `number of days`.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow, but it sounds like a gaps-and-islands problem?

Comment: The rules of generating NULLs for some intervals are not clear. For example what if an interval A is  in the union of B and C? Using integers, A= 2..6 while B=1..4 and C=3..7 .

Comment: @Serg im not sure what u mean by that, could u please explain it using some graphic.

Comment: A =      ************

Comment: And how are you deciding that only the 1st and 4th blocks count; why isn't 1st block 11 days (1-11th), 2nd block 4 days (12-15th), 3rd block 5 days (16-20th), and 4th block 11 days (21-31st)? Assuming the blocks are listed and evaluated in start-date order...

Comment: B+C=*****|**************

Comment: @serg because the first block starts sooner as the second or third and also has more days in his interval

Comment: Why do you output 2 blocks (block 1: 2022-08-01 to 2022-08-11 and block 4: 2022-08-11 to 2022-08-31) and not 4 blocks (block 1: 2022-08-01 to 2022-08-11, block 2: 2022-08-11 to 2022-08-15, block 3: 2022-08-15 to 2022-08-20 and block 4 2022-08-20 to 2022-08-31)? What is the logic of picking those blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH data(Block,Date_From,Date_until) AS (
    SELECT 1, TO_DATE('25.07.2022','DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_DATE('11.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, TO_DATE('05.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_DATE('15.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, TO_DATE('10.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_DATE('20.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, TO_DATE('11.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_DATE('05.09.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL
),
clipped(Block,Date_From,Date_until) AS (
    SELECT Block, GREATEST(Date_From, TO_DATE('01.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')), LEAST(Date_until, TO_DATE('31.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')) FROM DATA
)
SELECT c.*, 
    CASE WHEN NOT(
        EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clipped d WHERE d.Date_From < c.Date_until AND d.Date_until > c.Date_From AND d.block < c.block) 
        AND
        EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM clipped d WHERE d.Date_From < c.Date_until AND d.Date_until > c.Date_From AND d.block > c.block) )
        THEN c.Date_until - c.Date_from  ELSE NULL
    END AS days
FROM clipped c
ORDER BY c.block 
;


1   01/08/22    11/08/22    10
2   05/08/22    15/08/22    
3   10/08/22    20/08/22    
4   11/08/22    31/08/22    20
```

Comment: If the last sample data row is  `SELECT 4, TO_DATE('14.08.2022','DD.MM.YYYY'), TO_DATE('05.09.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL`  then 12.08 and 13.08 are not counted. Is it correct?